# Use jScript / AJAX to call PHP script but ONLY if form has been submitted?

Tags: javascript, function

This is kind of a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786942/merge-two-functions-in-jscript).

I have this code:

```
var chpass = function()
{
    var pass1 = encodeURIComponent($("#pass1").val());
    var pass2 = encodeURIComponent($("#pass2").val());
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib_ajax/somescript.php",
        data: "pass1="+ pass1+"&pass2="+ pass2,
        success: function(msg_pass)
        {
            $("#status_pass").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                if(msg_pass == 'empty pass1')
                {
                    $("#pass1").removeClass('green');
                    $("#pass1").addClass("red");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
$("#signup").ready(chpass);
$("#signup").change(chpass);
```

And in the php script:

```
$pass1 = trim($_POST['pass1']); 
if(!isset($pass1)||empty($pass1)) die('empty pass1');
```

My problem is that I don't want the form to be validated with ready() the first time the page is loaded but every time the page is loaded after a submit.

I have tried to figure out how to set a default event for the handler and then use preventDefault but I've been completely unsuccessful so far.

Could part of the problem be that when the page is submitted some additional validation happens on the server and in some cases I use header('Location: ') to reload the page?

Any tips how I can work this out? Is there a way to change it to something like:

```
if ( FORM IS SUBMITED ) $("#signup").ready(chpass);
```

Or maybe:

```
if ( FORM IS SUBMITED && msg_pass == 'empty pass1')
    {
         $("#pass1").removeClass('green');
         $("#pass1").addClass("red");
    }
```

Can also add that I have tried to change ready() to submit() with no luck:

```
$("#signup").submit(chpass); // DO NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. Change the code:

```
$("#signup").ready(chpass);
```

to:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>$("#signup").ready(chpass);<?php } ?>
```

and that part of the jScript is left out unless the form is submitted!